# right angle triangle to the right of odd *

Tags: c

i have an assignment to do a right angle triangle with an odd number (user gives us what number) and to make it to the right
example if user gives us 5:

```
*****
  ***
    *
```

i can use only stdio.h

where am i wrong ?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int x,i,y=0;
printf("select odd number:\n");
scanf("%d", &x);
for (i=x ; (i <= x)&&(i>0); i=i-2){
    for (y; y > 0; y=y-2){
        printf("_");
    }
    for (x; x >= 0; x-=2){
        printf("*");
    }
    x = x - 2;
    printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your outer loop is testing against `x` but within that you are again using `x` as a loop variable and when *that* loop ends you are setting x less than 0 with `x = x - 2`. So the outer loop condition isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer loop is testing against `x` but within that you are again using `x` as a loop variable and when *that* loop ends you are setting `x` less than `0` with `x = x - 2`. So the outer loop condition isn't going to work.